# Unignore Ionic Doctor Issue

Tags: ionic-framework, npm

I accidentally hit “Ignore forever” in an ionic doctor issue.
Is there any option to re-enable this issue? I looked in the projects config files but didn't find any changes. I also uninstalled / installed ionic but the issue is still ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be setting an `ignored` array in config.json file in `.ionic` folder or app configuration folder present in home directory. It may be that it is not a project level setting but cli config level.

```
 "state": {
    "lastCommand": "date-stamp",
    "doctor": {
      "ignored": [
        "app-scripts-update-available",
        "ionic-native-update-available"
      ]
    }
```

Deleting the contents of the array seems to show the ignored issues when doing `ionic doctor check`.

Comment: Thank you, sir! :)